# Erasing or making parts of svg paths transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg

I recently started working with SVG paths. I am using JavaScript SVG and Canvases to allow a user to draw dynamically using a mouse.

One of my problems is that when the user tries to draw on an already existing path, it takes a while to over ride it, I am wondering if there is an efficient/smoother way to do this.

My other problem is with erasing parts of an already drawn SVG path. I know I can use a different color (ex.white) to overdraw the path but if a background picture exists then it will still mask parts of the background. Is there anyway to edit parts of the path to become transparent or even deleting parts of it?

I tried getting the background color of the canvas and draw over the path using that color, but it only gets the color of the original point.

Thanks.

Comment: http://raphaeljs.com/ is a js library that is able to easily select sub-paths. You could then split a path into two sub-paths, excluding the part that was erased.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that is currently working for me is as follows.

- In the javascript file, an array is created. Also a counter.

  `var idArray = new Array();`
  `var idCounter = 0;`
- As the path is being created the id is pushed to the array.

  `idArray.push(idCounter);`
- Then by using the `"Name_of_path".attr('id',idCounter);` the id of the path is set.
- Now by looping over the ids using counter `i`, `i < idArray.length`, you can find which path is clicked on and remove it.

  `for(var i = 0;i<list.length;i++){`
  `$("#"+list[i]).click(function(){`
  `var v = "name_of_paper".getById($(this).id);`
  `$(this).remove();`
  `});`
- Also by defining a id class inside the styles you can change the opacity.

This solution just removes the path completely, I don't have a solution for removing parts of the path yet. Just a workaround.